# How to match text with images from arrays for a tooltip/hover text

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am displaying images on the front end via an array and when hovering over these images I want to display the names that are related to them.

The images work on an ngFor loop and are parsed to the parent component which displays them, I was thinking of adding the names which I want to display on hover to the same array so they can be accessed or even via a new one - this I can do, my problem is I don't know how to then get the names to be displayed when hovering over the images and for them to be the correct ones.

The images are taken from the data set and parsed through like below,
sessions also contain the the names i want to display under the roles array.

JS:

```
  participantImage = [];

  getParticipantDetails(session) {

  this.participantImage = session.roles.map(role => 
  role.account.thumbnailURL);
  return this.participantImage;
  }
```

HTML:

```
 [participantImages]="getParticipantDetails(session)"
```

now in the parent container the image array is used and displayed.

JS:

```
  @Input() participantImages?: any[] = [];
```

HTML:

```
     <div class="Session-Participants">
     <div  *ngFor="let image of participantImages" >
      <img [src]='image' width=100px/>
     </div>
     </div>
```

So what I want to do is when I hover over the image I want to correctly display the right name,

My initial thought, is to do the same thing, create an array of the the names like i do with the images with:

JS:

```
  participantNames = [];

  getParticipantNames(session) {

  this.participantNames = session.roles.map(role => 
  role.account.fullName);
```

HTML:

```
     [participantNames]="getParticipantNames(session)"
```

BUT then how would I actually use the names in the parent component to be shown on hover of the the images in:
Something like below??

HTML:

```
  <div class="Session-Participants">
  <div  *ngFor="let image of participantImages" 
        *ngFor="let name of participantNames"
         >
      <img [src]='image' width=100px/ // some kind of hover code and the name like {{ name }} ???      >
  </div>
```

Thank you very much if you can help!

Comment: Your code is a little confusing, but it would seem as though the most straightforward route would be to make your `image` and object like: `{url: '', title: ''}` and then in your html you can do `<img [src]='image?.url' width=100px [title]='image?.title' />`

Comment: I realise it is confusing sorry, okay but after I do that - will the hover work?

Comment: That [title] how would i make it hoverable? basically the way the codes working is the data is being parsed through a component with an ngfor, broken down by a function then that data is parsed to the parent component via the input which then displays the image array in the code that you have used

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title

Comment: oh so angulars method for doing it is [title]?

Comment: The `[]` is angular's way of binding to that html attribute. You are doing it with the src attribute already. You can do it with the title attribute(or any other html attribute) as well.